# How to fine tune a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am currently working on a project in which I am creating a neural network that predicts the type of pitch that a pitcher will throw. The network will receive 4 inputs (whether the hitter is left handed or right handed, balls, strikes, outs). I have created the network, however, I have run into some problems. The biggest problem is that the loss increases exponentially, and the accuracy decreases exponentially. Based on my research I believe that I need to use the adam optimizer and catergorical crossentropy loss function, however, I could be mistaken. I also have 2,818 rows of data, so I do believe that I have enough data.  I have minimal knowledge of neural networks, and I need some direction in how to fine tune this network.

```
import keras

model_3 = Sequential([
    Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), input_shape=(3,)),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)),
])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

model_3.compile(optimizer= optimizer,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
              
hist_3 = model_3.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=32, epochs=100,
          validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
```

I have played around with different architectures, loss functions, optimizers, and loss functions. I have changed the number of neurons in each layer. I have also experimented with the mean standard error, binary crossentropy, and other loss functions. I have also tried the sgd optimizer. Each modification created different variations of the same problem.

Comment: Exploding gradient is often caused by data distribution (features have very high values) or by a very high learning rate. Based on your example, weights are randomly initiated with a scaled version of the normal distribution, and expects data to be centered around 0 and low standard deviation (~1). Can you confirm you have preprocessed the data? If so, can you please provide more information about the data distribution and model output distribution?

Comment: Is your data numerical?